# How is the number of blades on a centrifugal compressor determined?

Tags: mechanical, turbomachinery

If I know the tip and hub diameter of a centrifugal compressor ,the inlet velocity and outlet velocity, how do I determine the number of blades on a centrifugal compressor?

Comment: This was asked recently, but can't find it, however this may help : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/6166/10902

Comment: It's a tradeoff between the stress in each blade for a given total torque (more force and stress per blade with fewer blades) and the amount of blockage and viscous drag caused by the blades (more blockage and drag with more blades).

Comment: What @alephzero is saying very gently is that this is an extremely tricky problem to solve and generally requires a lot of experiments.